# Appending multiple elements to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have `8` elements and I want to add them into a array in numpy. I used `np.append()` but it seems that I can only add two elements at one time. I want to add all `8` elements at once. `first_1 =35.72438966508524`, `first_2 = 35.73839550991734`, etc.

```
35.72438966508524 35.73839550991734 35.81944190992304 
35.80549149559467 35.78399019604507 36.03781192909738 
35.9957696566448 35.94692998938782

np.append(first_1,first_2,first_3,first_4,first_5,first_6,first_7,first_8)
```

The error is

> ```
> TypeError: append() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 8 were given
> ```

Comment: You probably want `np.concatenate`, but please format your question so it's at least somewhat readable.

Comment: I used it. But the error is concatenate() takes at most 3 arguments (8 given). Is there any other way I can add all  of them?

Comment: You're probably calling it wrong.  Use `np.concatenate([a,b,c,d,e,f,g...])`.  Don't pass each array as an argument, pass a list of the arguments.  In your case it would be `np.concatenate([first_1,first_2,first_3,first_4,first_5,first_6,first_7,first_8])`

Comment: the code is np.concatenate([first_1,first_2,first_3,first_4,first_5,first_6,first_7,first_8]). Still got an error: ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated

Comment: Then please provide an [mcve], as you  have not shown enough information to solve your problem.

Comment: `np.append` is a poorly named function that gives users lots of problems.  Learn to use `np.array` and `np.concatenate` correctly.

Answer (score 3):

```
first = 35.72438966508524 
second = 35.73839550991734 
third = 35.81944190992304
forth = 35.80549149559467 
fifth = 35.78399019604507 
sixth = 36.03781192909738 
seventh = 35.9957696566448 
eighth = 35.94692998938782
```

now to make a new numpy array:

```
a = np.array([first, second, third, forth, fifth, sixth, seventh, eighth])
```

output:

```
a
Out[89]: 
array([35.72438967, 35.73839551, 35.81944191, 35.8054915 , 35.7839902 ,
       36.03781193, 35.99576966, 35.94692999])
```

to append to existing array (using previously created 'a'):

```
a = np.append(a, [first, second, third, forth, fifth, sixth, seventh, eight], axis=0)
```

which gives:

```
a
Out[93]: 
array([35.72438967, 35.73839551, 35.81944191, 35.8054915 , 35.7839902 ,
       36.03781193, 35.99576966, 35.94692999, 35.72438967, 35.73839551,
       35.81944191, 35.8054915 , 35.7839902 , 36.03781193, 35.99576966,
       35.94692999])
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct syntax is (if I suppose that you wanted to append your 8 values to an numpy array named as `ar`:

```
np.append(ar, (first_1, first_2, first_3, first_4, first_5, first_6, first_7, first_8))
```

- The *first* argument is your original numpy array,
- The *second* one is the *tuple* (or the *list*, or other array-like object) of your values, so those values *have to be in the parentheses*.

Answer (score 1):

```
np.array([first_1,first_2,first_3,first_4,first_5,first_6,first_7,first_8])
```

Comment: TypeError: append() missing 1 required positional argument: 'values'. What does it mean?

Comment: @user3483203 `first_1`... aren't arrays, they are numbers lol

Comment: Well this was a terribly unclear question, my mistake :)

Comment: @user3483203 ahaha no problem, I did a double take as well, she worded it pretty poorly.